# can i put hot soup in mason jar for travel

Tags: food-safety

i ran out of glass containers (people haven't returned them) and i want to give my boyfriend hot soup for work.  Is it safe to put it in a mason jar and put the lid on while hot? And how long might the soup stay hot in it?

Comment: why not take your bf soup in a thermos cup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first part, about pouring hot soup in mason jars, it should be safe, but there's always a risk of shattering if the liquid is too hot.

There are many somewhat related topics regarding putting hot liquid in mason jars.

[Is it safe to put fresh hot soup in a glass mason jar?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/74782/is-it-safe-to-put-fresh-hot-soup-in-a-glass-mason-jar)

https://www.reddit.com/r/NoStupidQuestions/comments/9rd3y2/will_a_mason_jar_explode_if_i_put_it_into_boiling/

https://www.quora.com/Will-a-mason-jar-shatter-if-I-pour-hot-water-in-it
...

For the second part, It will not keep the soup hot/warm for a long time, it is not a "thermos" container.

Comment: For the issue of keeping it warm, see https://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/2782/67

Answer (score 2):

I have had mason jars break when filling with hot items.  It is best to warm the jar first, just by running hot water into it.  A someone else pointed out, a mason jar is, of course, not insulated.  You mention this is to take to work, I assume for lunch or dinner.  I also want to point out that you need to consider food safety, as your soup will soon be in the "danger zone."  [You should read this.](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/34670/how-do-i-know-if-food-left-at-room-temperature-is-still-safe-to-eat)  It is much safer to chill the soup to refrigeration temperature, pack it in a cooler, or refrigerate at work, then reheat at meal time.